# Problems with expected exceptions

Tags: java, testng, powermock

There is an issue reported here : http://code.google.com/p/powermock/issues/detail?id=366

I checked the class (Invoker) that checks the condition in Testng and the verification is made with `isAssignableFrom`

**Is there a reason for that, why not just compare class names ?** 
There is an issue in this case because different class loaders are used so this method return false and tests fails when they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first thing to check is why PowerMock is loading a second time an existing class with its own class loader, which is likely to cause other kinds of problems.

Comment: Ok i searched a bit, this is an issue with powermock. Thanks